# Text no overflow

Tags: html, css, sidenav

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this question, but I'll give it a try.

I have a website set up with a side navigation menu.  When the menu is opened, the body content is pushed all the way off screen making the text unreadable.  I want to know what css property I need to set to make the text overflow onto the next line.

An example of this can be seen in the [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push).  When the menu is opened, the text does not disappear behind the screen.

CSS

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}

body.push {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

p {
  color: red;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.navbar-custom {
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar-custom a {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-custom.color {
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar-custom.color a {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-custom.push {
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.navbar-custom.push a {
  color: black;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}

#main {
  padding-top: 50px;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

#main.push {
  margin-left: 300px;
}

#sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

#sidenav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#sidenav a {
  padding: 15px 8px 20px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#sidenav i {
  padding: 15px 8px 20px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sidenav a:hover,
#sidenav .offcanvas a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffcc00;
}

#sidenav .social {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 8px 20px 32px;
}

#sidenav .social i:hover {
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: #ffcc00;
}

#sidenav #nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#sidenav.toggled {
  width: 300px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  #sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  #sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  #main.push {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  #sidenav .social {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #sidenav.toggled {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .navbar-custom.push {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<section id="sidenav">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="social">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope"><a href="#" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><span
                    class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a></i>
      <i class="fa fa-github"><a target="_blank" href="#" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><span
                class="fa fa-github"></span></a></i>
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin"><a target="_blank" href="#"
                  class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a></i>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio <span class="fa fa-folder-open"></span></a></li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Resume <span class="fa fa-file"></span> </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <section class="container">
    <section class="navbar-header">
      <a onclick="toggleMenu()" class="navbar-brand">Menu <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </section>
  </section>
</nav>
<section id="main">
  <section class="container">
    <p>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    </p>
  </section>
</section>
```

JS

```
var main = $("#main");
var sidenav = $("#sidenav");
var body = $("body");
var navbarFixed = $(".navbar-fixed-top");
var navbar = $(".navbar-custom");

function toggleMenu() {
  main.toggleClass("push");
  sidenav.toggleClass("toggled");
  body.toggleClass("push");
  navbarFixed.toggleClass("push");
};
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so we can see the issue?

Comment: Sure one second

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a7smgo54/1/

Comment: I added the code. I'm not sure why the fiddle isn't working. Should i put a max-width on it?

Comment: You forgot to add jquery library on your fiddle :)

Comment: The Jquery library should be in there

Comment: I don't know why the code isn't working on JSFiddle. But The code above works when I localhost it.

Comment: I don't understand.  In the example, they are pushing the margin of the main body content to the left. What do you mean they aren't modifying the margins?

Comment: My apologies, I got confused myself. Try removing the "container" class from the section that is directly under the main div. This is setting a width which looks like it is preventing the wrap.

Comment: That did the trick